# Redirect mobile devices to a subdomain

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website and want to make it mobile friendly. I thought it would be nice to redirect the mobile devices to an extra subdomain. The concept is following.

How to detect that it is a mobile device?

Checking with Javascript if the device is bigger than 1000px like this:

```
if (screen.width <= 1000) {
document.location = "mobile.html";}
```

I'm not so good in Javascript so I dont know if there is an option to redirect to an URL instead of a document.

I have read that it is possible with the .htacces file but I have no clue how this code works which is in this file. Often there is no explanation how it detects mobile devices. I don't want some link with "Go here to mobile version".

Comment: " I thought it would be nice to redirect the mobile devices to an extra subdomain." — It isn't. It means you have two sites to maintain and one is likely to get out of date. Just create a responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect if the user is on a mobile I advise you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/6838730) as it presents a way to detect mobile users far more reliable than checking the screen size

The [MSDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) shows that you can simply put an URL in the `document.location` var as follow

```
if (screen.width <= 1000)
    document.location = 'mobile.mydmain.com'
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Learned something knew. I really have to learn Javascript^^

Comment: My pleasure ! Keep in mind that javascript is a surprising language so never assume something's behaviour based on its name !

Comment: Sure i check the green tip ;)